# Mongo: Is it a good practice to do collection.find() to return all items on a master node

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb

I have a background process that collects all the users from MongoDB, and do certain checks and processing on their accounts; This happens daily at midnight. My questions are:

1. Is it a good practice (in terms of performance) to do this:

   ```
   db.users.find()
   ```

   to retrieve all the users, or this might slow down the DB and it's advisable to
   follow some other practice?
2. Is it safe to do it on a master node?

PS This happens daily on a number of users close to 100K users

Comment: "good practice" according to which metric? If it is performance, then we need profiles to know if your system is impacted by it. If it is security, we might need more informations to give a concrete answer. The wording of your question could attract "Primarily opinion-based" close votes.

Comment: This is really a bit broad without seeing your intent of usage, but addressing in reverse 2. Everything costs, so there is certainly going to be "some" drain on resources. You might be able to take data from a secondary node, but it's still going to have an effect and possibly delay secondary updates. 1. You might alternately consider following changes in the Oplog instead, and apply operations as changes are made. It really all depends on what you are actually doing and to what end.

Comment: @Kyll, I meant in terms of performance. Question updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDb is not a single-thread database, your operation is run in a thread.

What you need to pay attention is set timeout to find operation.

eg.

```
db.users.find(timeout=false)
```

Otherwise, you will get a expired cursor exception after a period of time

There is another way to avoid long-time cursor, you query one document every time, and query next document by

```
db.users.findOne({_id: {$gt: old_id}})
```

Comment: Well I cannot think of any worthwhile database where such an operation would "block" other operations from occuring. But there still are relative "costs" incurred. Using/Re-allocating content in hot memory, storage I/O and network I/O, memory consumption for connection and query processing just to name a few. So I can't see how this can be a definitve answer to a pretty broad question already.